# How to compare Floats

Tags: java, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am using the Java IDE in Virtual BreadBoard (VBB).  I am trying to compare two float values, but this seems to fail.  I get no error, but the cursor on my breakpoint will not go past.  Here is my code, simplified:

```
void loop(){
        float val1= someFunctionThatReturnsAFloat();
        float val2= anotherFunctionThatReturnsAFloat();

        Serial.print(val1+ "\r\n" );
        Serial.print(val2 + "\r\n");
        int com = Float.compare(val1, val2);  //line with breakpoint
        delay(1000);        

    }
```

My cursor will not move past the:

```
 int com = Float.compare(val1, val2);
```

line.  Any suggestion on why this is?  I've tried adding this to the start of my class:

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
```

But that doesn't seem to help either.

thanks

Comment: How exactly would importing `java.util.Scanner` help?

Comment: Isn't that the point of a breakpoint?  To halt the execution?  Well, your cursor won't move past the line with the breakpoint so that works as expected.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes, it stops at the break point but will not move past it (step over or into it).  So, my question is why wont Float.compare evaluate?

Comment: If you simplify the problem, e.g. call `Float.compare()` in a `main()` method, are you able to step past it if you add a break point? There's nothing in the code you pasted that would prevent the debugger from stepping to the next line. The most likely explanation is you're misusing or misinterpreting the debugger.

Comment: I've never had problems with a debugger before and I have fair amount of experience using them.  Though, this IDE is new.  But, I am able to step over the rest of the code just fine.  When it gets here, I am unable to step over it.  I was wondering if maybe there was a library I needed to import?

Comment: I just want to compare two floats in an if, then statement but  I can't seem to do that.

Comment: @jason how is it you tagged this question with both `java` and `arduino-uno`? Since when the latter has a JVM on it? Did I miss something?

Comment: I am using Virtual Bread Box which has a Java IDE.  You can check it out here: http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/

Comment: @jason I understand that you are using a Java IDE, my question was: is this supposed to be *Arduino code* or *Java Code*? Also, what is **Float.compare()**? I can't find it in the library

Comment: Oh sorry.  Yes, it is Java.  I am trying to compare two floats in an If, Then statement.  I got this method here:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/float_compare.htm

Comment: But, I am not all that familiar with Java.  Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @jason if the code is Java, why did you tag it with *Arduino*? Java code can't run on the *Arduino*, *afaik*.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Again, I tagged it both as Java and Arduino because I am using Virtual Bread Board, which allows you to build virtual Arduino kits.  The language it uses it its IDE is Java.

Comment: Here is the site for it: http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/DocView.html?doc=Help/Help  Unfortunatly, I did not see a tag, here, for VBB or I would have tagged it as such.

Comment: I can't find a single reference pointing out what code should be written in the Arduino sketch on the website. Are you **sure** that you can use arbitrary **Java** library functionality within *setup()* and *loop()* in your *Arduino emulator*? It sounds *very* counter-intuitive to me.. as it would emulate something that isn't available at deploy time.

Comment: Am I sure?  No, I am new to both Arduino an this app.  Here is a tutorial using Java (though the class is an extension of another class): http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/Project.html?project=GettingStarted4_ProgramArduino

Comment: @jason the very first paragraph says *"You might have noticed that the program is a Java program based on the Processing heritage of Arduino. However despite trying very hard to pretend to be Java Arduino is actually a C program. The Arduino Toolkit has a limited capability for exporting the Java syntax version used in VBB to the C version used by Arduino IDE."*, thus I am pretty confident you **cannot** use the java Float class there. If you want to know how to do float comparison, you should explain what are you trying to achieve? an equality test?

Comment: Yes.  I am just trying to do an if/then statement.  If one number is larger than another, do something.  So, I should be doing this in C?  It's odd that the IDE says the files are Java.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jason sorry for late reply, i didn't see your message, please use tags. It is java code, but you cannot use **any** java code, only java code that matches what you can write on an actual Arduino.